# apply list-style-type to ul or li

Tags: html, css

I cant seem to find a conclusive answer on whether i should be applying the style list-style-type ( or any of it's relatives ) to ul/ol tags or to the li tag. This is probably because it doesn't make any difference but maybe someone could confirm that and offer a suggestion as to best practice.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

the best practice is to assign list styles to the list itself (ul, ol), and li's will have it because of the cascading

from w3 css2.1 recommendation:

> Inheritance will transfer the 'list-style' values from OL and UL elements to LI elements. This is the recommended way to specify list style information.

however, ie6 and 7 won't recognize this inheritance correctly, so you'll have to apply the list styles to li elements if you plan to support them

Comment: Thanks. Can i just clarify exactly - that this effectively means that for support of IE6&7 this means one would need to apply list-style-type to both ul (or ol) and li .

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from the [W3C documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-list-style-type), it applies to elements with `display: list-item`, that means to `ul` and `ol` elements.

Comment: actually, `ul` and `ol` have `display:block`. `li` is abbr for `list item`

Comment: True. Anyway the property is **inherited** so the li elements get it.